# Export data from Prod to Lower environment Daily based on the Date column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to setup a process which Exports the daily data from Production Staging tables to Test Staging Tables.I would like to schedule this export daily from Prod to Test. These staging tables contains the daily data. So, Is there any way I can truncate the Test staging Tables and then loads the data from Production to Test Daily for all the tables in a database?

I tried using linked server. But, I was not able to get is work.

Comment: How many records are we talking about?  What about SSIS, have you tried that?

Comment: There are 58 tables each containing the records ranging from 50 to 220000

Comment: As long as you have a server which can access both Prod and lower environments, you can use SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this stored procedure on my job to deal with a similar situation, that could be helpful for you:

```
CREATE Proc DumpFromPRO(@prodServ sysname, @prodDBname sysname = null) as
declare @sql nvarchar(MAX)
declare @XD table (ts sysname,tn sysname)

set nocount on

if not exists (select 1 from sys.servers where is_linked=1 and name=@prodServ)
begin
    raiserror ('Linked server not found.',19,1) with log
    set noexec on
end
if @prodDBname is null
    select top 1 @prodDBname = TABLE_CATALOG from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

set @sql = ''
select @sql +=
          'alter table ' + quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' nocheck constraint all; '
        + 'alter table ' + quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' disable trigger all; '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
exec (@sql)

set @sql = ''
select @sql +=
          'delete ' + quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' with (TABLOCK); '
        + 'alter index all on ' + quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' rebuild; '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
exec (@sql)

select @sql =
     'select schema_name(t.schema_id) as ts,t.name as tn from '+quotename(@prodServ)+'.'+quotename(@prodDBname)
    +'.sys.tables t join '+quotename(@prodServ)+'.'+quotename(@prodDBname)
    +'.sys.partitions p on (t.object_id=p.object_id and p.index_id in (0,1)) '
    +'group by schema_name(schema_id),t.name having sum(p.rows)>0'

insert @XD exec (@sql)

set @sql = ''
select @sql +=
    case
        when exists (
            select 1 from sys.columns
            where [object_id] = object_id(t.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+t.TABLE_NAME)
                and is_identity = 1)
        then  'set identity_insert ' + quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + t.TABLE_NAME + ' on; '
        else  ''
    end
    + 'insert ' + quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + t.TABLE_NAME + ' with (TABLOCK) ('
    + stuff((select ', ' + COLUMN_NAME
              from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              where TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
                and DATA_TYPE not in ('timestamp','rowversion')
              for xml path('')), 1, 2, '')
    + ') select ' 
    + stuff((select ', ' + COLUMN_NAME
              from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              where TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
                and DATA_TYPE not in ('timestamp','rowversion')
              for xml path('')), 1, 2, '')
    + ' from ' + quotename(@prodServ) + '.' + quotename(@prodDBname) + '.' + t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + t.TABLE_NAME + '; ' +
    case
        when exists (
            select 1 from sys.columns
            where [object_id] = object_id(t.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+t.TABLE_NAME)
                and is_identity = 1)
        then  'set identity_insert ' + quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + t.TABLE_NAME + ' off; '
        else  ''
    end
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
join @XD x on (t.TABLE_SCHEMA=x.ts and t.TABLE_NAME=x.tn)
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
exec (@sql)

set @sql = ''
select @sql +=
      'alter table ' + quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' check constraint all; '
    + 'alter table ' + quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' enable trigger all; '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
exec (@sql)

DBCC CheckConstraints with ALL_CONSTRAINTS
set noexec off
```